# JavaScript Regular Expressions and Capture Groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Im new to regular expressions in JavaScript and am having trouble getting an array of matches from a text string as seen below:

```
Sentence would go here
-foo
-bar
Another sentence would go here
-baz
-bat
```

I would like to get an array of matches like this:

```
match[0] = [
    'foo',
    'bar'
]
match[1] = [
    'baz',
    'bat'
]
```

So to summarize, I'm looking for is:

"*any dash+word (-foo, -bar, etc) that comes **AFTER** a sentence*"

Can anyone supply a formula that would capture all iterations instead of the last one as a repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration apparently. Forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm using regex101 if anyone wants to send me some tests

Comment: It may be easier to just iterate over all lines and collect the data as desired.

Comment: Are the hyphens always at the start of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match two lines starting with `-` and preceded by a newline if this is sufficient.

```
\n-(.*)\r?\n-(.*)
```

See [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xD0hN2/1). To get matches use [exec() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

```js
var re = /\n-(.*)\r?\n-(.*)/g; var m;

var str = 'Sentence would go here\n-foo\n-bar\nAnother sentence would go here\n-baz\n-bat';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) re.lastIndex++;
  document.write(m[1] + ',' + m[2] + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with this with your help: (^\"[\s\S]*?\")\n-(.*)\r?\n-(.*)

Comment: The only thing is 'match two lines' where I will need to 'match N lines'. I will figure this out however, thank you again

Comment: @bobblebubble. You do not need to increment the `lastIndex` because by using the `g` flag will automatically do that for you.

Comment: @Coldstar Welcome! Oh, I thought you want to match like pairs. Mabye just need `\r?\n-(.*)` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/jV0xQ6/2) but seems you figured out a solution already.

Comment: @TMKelleher Thank you for your comment! Used regex101 code generator which produced this. I'll leave it and upvote your annotation.

Comment: @bobblebubble. Thanks, it seems the OP does not want a regex like that either (check the second regex in my answer), because `\r?\n-(.*)` groups the dash+words together. Also, that regex would ignore the first `-` when capturing.

Comment: The `if (m.index === re.lastIndex) re.lastIndex++;` is redundant since the regex does not match an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The first regex I came up with is the following:

```
/([^-]+)(-\w*)/g
```

The first group `([^-]+)` grabs everything that is not a dash. We then follow that up the actual capture group we want `(-\w+)`. The we add the flag `g` to make the regular expression object keep track of the last place it looked. This means, each time we run `regex.exec(search)` we get the next match what you see in regex101.

Note: The `\w` for *JavaScript* is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So, if you just want letters use this instead of `\w`: `[a-zA-Z]`

---

Here is the code that implements this regular expression.

```
<p id = "input">
    Sentence would go here
    -foo
    -bar
    Another sentence would go here
    -baz
    -bat
</p>

<p id = "output">

</p>

<script>
    // Needed in order to make sure did not get a sentence.
    function check_for_word(search) {return search.split(/\w/).length > 1}
    function capture(regex, search) {
        var 
        // The initial match.
            match  = regex.exec(search),
        // Stores all of the results from the search.
            result = [],
        // Used to gather results.
            gather;
        while(match) {
            // Create something empty.
            gather = [];
            // Push onto the gather.
            gather.push(match[2]);
            // Get the next match.
            match = regex.exec(search);
            // While we have more dashes...
            while(match && !check_for_word(match[1])) {
                // Push result on!
                gather.push(match[2]);
                // Get the next match to be checked.
                match = regex.exec(search);
            };
            // Push what was gathered onto the result.
            result.push(gather);
        }
        // Hand back the result.
        return result;
    };
    var output = capture(/([^-]+)(-\w+)/g, document.getElementById("input").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
</script>
```

---

Using a slightly modified regular expression, you might get more of what you are looking for.

```
/[^-]+((?:-\w+[^-\w]*)+)/g
```

The extra bit of `[^-\w]*` allows for there to be some sort of separation between each dash word. Then the non-capturing group `(?:)` was added to allow the `+` one or more of the dashes. We also do not need the `()` around `[^-]+`, because the data is no longer needed as you will see below. The first is more flexible as to what can break between dash words, but I find this one a lot cleaner.

```js
function capture(regex, search) {
    var 
 // The initial match.
     match  = regex.exec(search),
 // Stores all of the results from the search.
     result = [],
 // Used to gather results.
  gather;
 while(match) {
     // Create something empty.
     gather = [];
  
     // Break up the large match.
     var temp = match[1].split('-');
  for(var i in temp) 
  {
      temp[i] = temp[i].split(/\W*/).join("");
   // Makes sure there was actually something to gather.
      if(temp[i].length > 0)
          gather.push("-" + temp[i]);
  }
  
  // Push what was gathered onto the result.
  result.push(gather);
  
  // Get the next match.
  match = regex.exec(search); 
 };
 // Hand back the result.
 return result;
};
var output = capture(/[^-]+((?:-\w+[^-\w]*)+)/g, document.getElementById("input").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<p id = "input">
Sentence would go here
-foo
-bar
Another sentence would go here
-baz
-bat
My very own sentence!
-get
-all
-of
  -these!
</p>

<p id = "output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp captures do not really work well with unbounded number of groups. Rather, splitting works better here:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent;
var blocks = text.split(/^(?!-)/m);
var result = blocks.map(function(block) {
  return block.split(/^-/m).slice(1).map(function(line) {
      return line.trim();
    });
});
document.getElementById('text').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="text">Sentence would go here
-foo
-bar
Another sentence would go here
-baz
-bat
</div>
```